# How can I save data entered in my python program in another file?

Tags: python

The purpose is to save the data entered in my program's input in a notepad or file from which Python can gather the information for the next time I run the program.

**Example:**

`name = str(input("Register person: "))` <-- save this value in a file so I can use it even after I close the program, storing it in a list, dictionary or external file using some module/library...

I just want to save some data **without overwriting** the file everytime i run the program, storing more data like a database, so i can register new "persons" or whatever i want in this file.

Comment: You need to create file and open it in append mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `open()`. Add the file you want to open, and the mode as arguments. 'a' means append, which in your case will be the best to use.

```
name = str(input("Register person: "))

with open('text.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open file in append mode to append data into it

```
name = str(input("Register person: "))

with open('stored_data.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `with open` function. So if you want to write something in a file you can do it with:

```
with open("test.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("Your String/Dictionary/Datatype")
```

if you want to append something, just change the `w` with the `a` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in 'a' mode and add a end of line.

```
name = str(input("Register person: "))
with open('text2.txt', 'a') as file:
    file.write(f"{name}\n")
```